# Problems embedding an XML file with associated XSD in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xsd, flash-builder

EDITx2: The problem below seems to be caused by attributes related to my XML schema, which I'm using primarily so I can validate my XML in FB 4.7 and aren't really needed once the XML is embedded in the app itself.

Creating an XML object identical to my XML document but omitting the xmlns, xmlns:xsi, and xsi:schemalocation attributes results in an XML object in AS that can be properly navigated. Including them not only causes the problems below, but also causes the xmlns and xmlns:xsi attributes to be carried down the tree, making XMLList-based subsets of the original XML object equally difficult to dissect. The code examples below have been updated to show the phenomenon.

The question now becomes: Can I strip the schema-related attributes when I embed the XML somehow, or otherwise make them more AS-friendly?

EDIT: The problem I'm experiencing seems to be specifically related to an embedded XML document; XML variables created directly in AS3 can be traversed normally.

I'm having a seemingly nonsensical problem in AS3. Let's assume an XML document called example.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myParent xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/Schema Schema.xsd">
  <myChild id="1">
    <myGrandchild cid="1" />
    <myGrandchild cid="2" />
  </myChild>
  <myChild id="2">
    <myGrandchild cid="3" />
  </myChild>
</myParent>
```

I then try to assign it to a static constant (so as to be accessible outside its native class) in AS3 via embedding, like this:

```
[Embed(source="example.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private static const exampleXML:Class;
public static const myXML:XML = XML(new exampleXML);
```

I then want to extract elements/nodes from this with an XMLList. Here's what I'm running into. Here are two examples that work as I'd expect them to, followed by three that don't:

```
// #1
var myList:XMLList = myXML.*;
trace(myList);
/*
  <myChild id="1" xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <myGrandchild cid="1" />
    <myGrandchild cid="2" />
  </myChild>
  <myChild id="2" xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <myGrandchild cid="3" />
  </myChild>
*/

// #2
var myList:XMLList = myXML.*.(@id==1);
trace(myList);
/*
  <myChild id="1" xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <myGrandchild cid="1" />
    <myGrandchild cid="2" />
  </myChild>
*/

// #3
var myList:XMLList = myXML.myChild;
trace(myList);
/*
  (Outputs nothing at all)
*/

// #4
var myList:XML = myXML.myChild[0];
trace(myList);
/*
  null
*/

// #5
var myList:XMLList = myXML.child("myChild");
trace(myList);
/*
  (Outputs nothing at all)
*/
```

In theory, #3 and #5 SHOULD give identical output to #1, and #4 should give identical output to #2. Why are 3-5 coming out blank? Is there an issue with declaring myXML as static or constant? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using a very generic example here, obviously. The actual XML I'm working with is tied to an XSD schema; if that could have any possible bearing on my problem let me know and I'll post my actual code.

Comment: it [works for me](http://wonderfl.net/c/apuN)....

Comment: also id attributes should be unique within the document. see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/)

Comment: Edited; looks like it's specific to an embedded document. I'm using a very generic example; the original document, which I'll post if needed, doesn't have any repeated attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //Since a namespace was defined in The xml you need access it via the namespace Object 
  var myXML:XML = 
  <myParent xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/Schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/Schema Schema.xsd">
    <myChild id="1">
      <myGrandchild cid="1" >fus</myGrandchild>
      <myGrandchild cid="2" >ro</myGrandchild>
    </myChild>
    <myChild id="2">
      <myGrandchild cid="3" >do</myGrandchild>
    </myChild>
  </myParent>

  // to access nodes that are in a non-default namespace you must first create a namespace object
  var myChildns:Namespace = new Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2000/Schema');
  trace(myXML..myChildns::myChild.(@id  == '1').myChildns::myGrandchild.(@cid  == '1').toString())// traces out fus
```

Answer (score 0):

Every XML document belongs to some implicit namespace, that namespace is usually "" or empty string. By using the xmlns attribute you are changing the implicit namespace used by unprefixed nodes in the document -- which is why you are seeing the namespace attributes "moving" around when you sub-select a node or group of nodes within the document.

When the `xmlns` attribute is present, then when querying for them using e4x, you must qualify your selection, otherwise they wont match. For example:

```xml
<paystub:section></paystub:section>
```

is not the same thing as:

```xml
<article:section></article:section>
```

You can explicitly query for node in a namespace by using (like The_asMan suggested, while I was typing this):

```as
namespace schema = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/Schema'
var list:XMLList = myXml.schema::myChild;
var node:XML = myXml.schema::myChild[0];
```

Or you can set the "use" a schema for a scope with the following, and then query unqualified:

```as
namespace schema = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/Schema'

use namespace schema;

var list:XMLList = myXml.myChild;
var node:XML = myXml.myChild[0];
```

Which should return the same, correct results. See the [example here](http://wonderfl.net/c/fhCf)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, finally figured this one out. I've managed to sanitize the XML of all XMLNS and XSI declarations using a regular expression:

```
[Embed(source="example.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private static const exampleXML:Class;
public static const myXML:XML = clean(new XML(new exampleXML));

private static function clean(xml:XML):XML {
  var myXmlStr:String = xml.toString();
  var xmlPattern:RegExp = new RegExp("(xmlns|xsi)[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"", "gi");
  myXmlStr = myXmlStr.replace(xmlPattern, "");
  xml = new XML(myXmlStr);
  return xml;
}
```

The resulting XML object can now be traversed normally, it's still a static constant so I can access it without creating an instance of the class, and I can keep my schema intact as I edit the XML document itself.